# Laravel get belongsToMany through hasMany

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have 3 models: `Conference`, `Session` and `Speaker`. A Conference can have many Sessions and many Sessions can have many Speakers.

### Database structure

```
conferences
-----------
id
name


sessions
--------
id
conference_id
name


session_speaker
---------------
id
session_id
speaker_id


speakers
--------
id
name
```

I need to write a method which allows me to get all the Speakers of a particular Conference (so all the Speakers from all the Sessions of that particular Conference).

The following illustrates what I think *should* work, but it obviously doesn't as I can't chain these together.

### app/models/Conference.php

```
class Conference extends Eloquent {

  public function speakers() {
    return $this->hasMany('Session')->belongsToMany('Speaker');
  }

}
```

I have all the Model-Model relationships setup and working correctly (Conference-Sessions, Session-Speakers) however I can't create the bridge between Conference-Sessions-Speakers. Does anyone know how I can achieve this without writing a large SQL join query?

I think if there was a relationship `belongsToManyThrough()` this would work however there isn't.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, the hasManyThrough relation does not work with many to many relationships in between.

What you can do is something like this:

```
public function speakers() {
  $session_ids = Session::where('conference_id', $this->id);
  $speaker_ids = DB::table('session_speaker')->whereIn('session_id', $session_ids)->lists('speaker_id');
  return Speaker::whereIn('id', $speaker_ids)->get();
}
```

You probably need to set the variables to `array(0)` if no results are found, otherwise the whereIn function will throw an error.
You could also use an Eloquent-only way, but that would probably result in many more database queries, while this one should be fine with only 2 queries being run.

You can then access the speakers with e.g. `Conference::find(1)->speakers()`.

**Note from 2021**:
This answer is from back in 2014 and relates to Laravel 4. Nowadays, this apparently does not work anymore. I would encourage you to check the Laravel docs, maybe this problem can now be solved in a better way.

Comment: Got a few people on Twitter saying it's not possible too, but thanks for your reply - I think it's the best of a bad situation!

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()`

Comment: This answer is around 7 years old and is related to Laravel 4.

Answer (score 1):

I think a cleaner way will be

```php
public function speakers()
{
    return Speaker::whereHas('sessions', fn($query) => $query->where('conference_id', $this->id))->get();
}
```

but you should set up the ***belongsToMany()*** relationship between *Session* and *Speaker* Models